# How to fix " Error: Can't resolve '@arcgis/core/MapView' "

Tags: reactjs, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

i am trying to display a map with ArcGis Js Api in ReactJS

```
import Map from "@arcgis/core/Map";
import WebMap from "@arcgis/core/WebMap";
import MapView from "@arcgis/core/MapView";


function Test() {

    const webmap = new WebMap({
        portalItem: {
          id: "e691172598f04ea8881cd2a4adaa45ba"
        }
      });
      
      /************************************************************
       * Set the WebMap instance to the map property in a MapView.
       ************************************************************/
      const view = new MapView({
        map: webmap,
        container: "viewDiv"
      });

    return(

        <div>
            <div id="viewDiv"></div>
        </div>

    )
  };
  

  export default Test;
```

but i get the error " Error: Can't resolve '@arcgis/core/MapView' "

i tried to fix the error with re-installing the module @arcgis/core, Webpack and others but i couldn't fix it

can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path to `MapView` incorrect, you miss `views` directory. Try `import MapView from "@arcgis/core/views/MapView";` like in [official docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html)

Comment: thank you it works !

i didn't notice the path was wrong